# random size and position of many div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

This is my codepen: https://codepen.io/duonglam271/pen/pdyWgy

```
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

however, i want to make many bubbles like that with different size and position like this http://www.littlebeing.org/
please help me

Comment: Copy/pasting some css from a website is not enough for making a question. Lets write down your code, then ask your question, i mean try to do it first...

Comment: is there any reason why you want to use keyframes in CSS instead of jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried? Creating an empty div is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to create more bubbles, i think you should use appendChild method in javascript
2. If you want to random size and position, let take a look for CSS Variables (Custom Properties) or another way to create CSS global variables.
3. Set random value with random() function in CSS preprocessors like Sass to beautify your animation